# CopyToDataTable clears original metadata of DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, metadata

I am trying to sort a datatable. So, did the following code:

```
var dataTable = ds.Tables[DataTableName];
DataTable tempDataTable;
tempDataTable = dataTable.Clone();

tempDataTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()                                                        
.OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("fieldname"))                                                            
.ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>(sortColumn)).CopyToDataTable();

// issue here. it doesnt return the original table name but "Table1"
string tableN = tempDataTable.TableName; 

ds.Tables.Remove(dataTable);
ds.Tables.Add(tempDataTable); // add the sorted data table
```

Thanks

Comment: the clone maybe does not copy the table name.  you can still set the table name yourself or ref using index instead

Comment: thanks. ok, is there any deep CopyToDataTable() thing?

Comment: I am not sure, but what happens if you try `ds.Tables[DataTableName].DefaultView.Sort =" FieldName SortDirection";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort a DataTable you do not need to copy/clone it.

```
DataTable dataTable = Common.LoadFromDB();
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "fieldname ASC, " + sortColumn + " DESC";
dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: This will sort on one column. I need two columns.. the field “fieldname” doesnt get displayed but is just for grouping..

Comment: It has 2 columns. But you can just not display the column `fieldName` in the Control you are using the datatable.